# merge duplicate cells corresponding to a user and each cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with around 50000 rows and around 1200 columns. Each row is corresponding to a user and each cell is the products he bought. I need to identify duplicated product and delete it.

```
  A   |   B  |   C  |   D  |   E  |   F  |   G  |   H
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|--------
user1 | pro1 | pro1 | pro2 | pro3 | pro4 | pro3 | pro2...  
user2 | pro1 | pro3 | pro1 | pro3 | pro2 | pro3 | pro2..  
user3 | pro1 | pro3 | pro2 | pro3 | pro1 | pro3 | pro2..  
user4 | pro1 | pro1 | pro2 | pro5 | pro3 | pro3 | pro2..
```

to

```
  A   |   B  |   C  |   D  |   E  |   F  |   G  |   H
------|------|------|------|------|------|------|-------
user1 | pro1 | pro2 | pro3 | pro4 |      |      |
user2 | pro1 | pro2 | pro3 |      |      |      |  
user3 | pro1 | pro2 | pro3 |      |      |      |
user4 | pro1 | pro2 | pro3 | pro5 |      |      |
```

i tried a code but it works for 100  rows but for 30000 rows is goes to not responding

Comment: Please show your your [mcve] so we might get a chance to help you solving your problem...

Comment: Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. You might want to read the help on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) once again. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub UniqueValsInRow()
    Dim MyCol As New Collection
    Dim ColItem
    Dim CellVal As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, ColCount As Long
    Dim vTemp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet

    Set wsInput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   '---> enter you sheet name here
    LastRow = wsInput.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   '---> will give no. of rows

    For r = 1 To LastRow
        LastColumn = wsInput.Cells(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   '---> will give no. of columns in each row

        'add values to collection
        For c = 2 To LastColumn
            CellVal = wsInput.Cells(r, c).Value
            On Error Resume Next
            MyCol.Add CellVal, Chr(34) & CellVal & Chr(34)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next c

        'sort items in collection
        For i = 1 To MyCol.Count - 1
            For j = i + 1 To MyCol.Count
                If MyCol(i) > MyCol(j) Then
                   vTemp = MyCol(j)
                   MyCol.Remove j
                   MyCol.Add vTemp, vTemp, i
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        'delete row data
        wsInput.Range(Cells(r, 2), Cells(r, LastColumn)).ClearContents

        'enter unique sorted items from collection to row
        ColCount = 2
        For Each ColItem In MyCol
            wsInput.Cells(r, ColCount).Value = ColItem
            ColCount = ColCount + 1
        Next

        Set MyCol = New Collection
    Next r
End Sub
```

This is result I get after running the code:

[image]

[image]

**Note**: Take the backup of your data before running the code.

@SiddharthRout's and @DickKusleika's code has been referred to write above code.

Comment: The code seems to only compare the next cell in the adjacent column rather all the cells in that row. so pro1, pro3, pro1 is coming as same instead of pro1, pro3.

Comment: @Karthik - I've added images, the code works fine for me. If you can share your file I can look into it.

Comment: @ Mrig -sorry for the delay. The code is working fine. Thanks.